# Chrome extension: chrome.scripting.executeScript not working after using chrome.runtime.getURL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

After chasing the issue from:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1191971,
I got another question form example(mv3.zip):
if I rewrite the url('https://www.example.org/') into chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html'),chrome.scripting.executeScript didn't work,can someone help me with it?thank you.

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  await chrome.windows.create({ url:chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html')/*'https://www.example.org/'*/ },window =>{
    const tabId = window.tabs[0].id;
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId },
      function: () =>document.body.textContent = 'GOOD',
    }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError && complain(tabId));
  });});
```

[result of www.example.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha4rf.png)

[result of popup.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yOPf.png)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for replying.But is there a way to inject remote JS into extension pages?Because I need to run dynamic js files on those pages.How can I rewrite my code to achieve?

Comment: And why the script loaded successful in 'https://www.example.org/'? What different between 'https://www.example.org/' and getURL('popup.html')?Sorry,these question just came out from my head.

Comment: Content scripts are designed for web pages, the example.com page is a web page, which is why it can run content scripts. Your extension page is a chrome-extension:// page, a special privileged protocol not a part of the web, so it can't run content scripts, but since it's still a standard DOM page, its main script can create a new `script` element and set its src to the new script. For example your background script can send a message to the popup and the popup script will add a script element.